# slicing subset of list in a dict: how to turn index to integer?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, subset

From user input you can get an expression, which indicates what elements you want from a dict:

```
key[0]
key[0:2]
key[-1]
```

`key` is the key from the dict. The values in the dict are stored as a list. Therefore if the user puts `key[0]`, the first element from the values list should be returned.

Now, I got this to work by using:

```
input = ['key[0]']
key = input[0].split('[')[0]
index = self[0].split('[')[1].replace(']', '')
return dict[key][int(index)]
```

A little ugly, I gotta admit, but it works for well normal integers. The problem is when trying to get a subset like `key[0:2]`, since obviously `0:2` is not an integer.
How can I get this to work anyways? Is there maybe an even more efficient way to do this?

PS: I tried it with `eval(index)` as well, but same problem...

Comment: write a function that parses the string input and handle it however you like. identify if it is an integer or a slice statement then handle accordingly. I find allowing a user to give a string input to access my data clumsy so I wouldn't do that anyhow.

Comment: @PatrickArtner I'm not sure if I understood this correctly, but how would it even take the slice statement as such? wouldn't it still be a string and take me back to the initial issue?

Comment: Please post a [MCVE]

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a function that processes your user input and handles (or fails) all possible user input (*hence why I would not be keen to do that - users do stupid stuff all the times*):

```
def check_and_return(d, inp):
    """Not usable in production - handles not all cases. 
    Does not check if d is a dict. You are warned."""
    inp = str(inp) # make sure it is a string

    if not inp.strip():
        raise AttributeError("bad input")

    # not handled: input of "justakeynobracket"
    key, arg = inp.split("[", 1)  # may raise on invalid input - not handled

    def intOrNoneOrThrow(s):
        return int(s) if s.strip() else None

    if key in d:
        arg = arg.strip("]").split(":")
        lenArg = len(arg)
        if lenArg == 1:
            arg = int(arg[0])  # may raise ValueError
            return d[key][arg]  # retunrs 1 value
        elif 1 < lenArg < 4:
            # may raise ValueError
            start = intOrNoneOrThrow (arg[0])
            stop = intOrNoneOrThrow (arg[1])  
            # handle steps
            step = None
            if lenArg == 3:
                step = intOrNoneOrThrow(arg[2])
                
            return d[key][slice(start,stop,step)]  # returns a list

    else:
        raise KeyError(f"Not a key: '{key}'")
```

Usage / Test:

```
d = {"key":[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]}

for i in ['key[:5:-1]','key','key[1]','key[1:4]','not[0]','key[-1:-7:-2]','']:
    try:
        print(check_and_return(d, i))
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

Output:

```
[8, 7]
not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
2
[2, 3, 4]
"Not a key: 'not'"
[8, 6, 4]
bad input
```

Comment: Fails for example `key[::-1]` because your defaults are incorrect. Could do the whole `elif` part with `return d[key][slice(*(int(i) if i.strip() else None for i in arg))]`

Comment: @KellyBundy thanks for pointing that out.  Your one liner is nice, I adapted/fixed it differently for debugging purposes - no way to set breakpoints inside one liners and _"""Not usable in production - handles not all cases. Does not check if d is a dict. You are warned."""_ still applies.

Comment: Hi!! thanks for ur answer! i was looking for sth less lengthy, but this will be helpful once I progress a bit further with my code. appreciate ur help a lot :)